# local-storage, the simple way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a working code which changes the text of a button and panel if you click button 1, two or three.
See this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgKOba

I now want to use local-storage, in this way: when you first visit the page, the default text is displayed.
When you have clicked button X, the button and panel text changes. The id is stored in local-storage. When you reload the page, it sees there's something in the local-storage and uses that to change the button and panel text.

I tried it this way: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoPOQv

That codepen contains this html:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="panel"> 
    <h2>Panel Header</h2>
    <p>default text</p>
</div> <!-- /panel -->

<div class="container">
  <a href="#panel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow" id="panel_button"> <p>default text</p></a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#tt_popup" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all btn" id="btn1" data-transition="flip">Button 1</a>
```

And this javascript:

```
// if we have something on local storage 
if(localStorage.getItem('id')) {
$("#panel p").html("This is info about stop <b>" + this.id + "</b>."); //then set this html text to the panel p
      $("#panel_button p").html("Info about stop " + this.id + "."); // and change the button text
}

$(document).on("ready", function () {
    $(".btn").on("click", function () { //if a button with class btn is clicked

      $("#panel p").html("This is info about stop <b>" + this.id + "</b>."); //then set this html text to the panel p
      $("#panel_button p").html("Info about stop " + this.id + "."); // and change the button text
      localStorage.setItem('id', this.id);        //also add the last-clicked id to the local-storage

    });

});
```

As you can see I used an if-statement I found on google somewhere to check if the local-storage is empty, and if it is not execute some rules.

But as you also can see it doesn't display the default text, neither does it read the local-storage correctly.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: From DOC: `There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to .on( "ready" ) the bound handler will not be executed.`

Comment: @A. Wolff What does that mean? That the if-statement is not in the correct place? Because without the if-statement the `$(document).on("ready"` works perfectly, as seen in the first codepen.

Comment: That was for information purpose only, you shouldn't use this syntax

Comment: Ok thanks, but do I sound rude if I say I was so happy I had finally found something that worked, that I don't really care? This question is about local-storage, which is now my first goal.

Comment: If you don't care, who cares? Sorry if i was off topic, just wanted to point it. Your issue about localstorage as nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to wrong `id`. `this.id` is not the id you get from the localStorage. Fixed it for you:

```
// if we have something on local storage
var id = localStorage.getItem('id');
if(id) {
    $("#panel p").html("This is info about stop <b>" + id + "</b>."); //then set this html text to the panel p
    $("#panel_button p").html("Info about stop " + id + "."); // and change the button text
}
```

Comment: You're right, I just edited the codepen and it works perfectly! It doesn't work on my website yet, but I will figure that out eventually.

Comment: Notice that you have to run that code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ // code here });` or place it after the html markup (just before `</body>`).

Comment: Or in your case document.ready is `$(document).on("ready", function () {// code here });`

Comment: I would rather go with that on too @plalx

Comment: You were right balzafin, that was my mistake there. I guess i'm just sleepy or something... @plalx That's a neat two lines of rules you wrote there! I don't understand how it works, but fact is it does work perfectly. Thanks a lot for that one!

Comment: Even more, @Plalx's code seems to simulate a button click, and by coincidence that activates more things on my website which is awesome!